# Find the lambda-terme without free variables of the following types?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Could someone please explain the process of finding the lambda-terme without free variables of the following types ? I have some idea on how I should solve this but I'm not really sure it's the right way.

a) p->(q->q)
b) (p->q)->((q->r)->(p->r))
c) (p->(q->(q->r)))->(p->(q->r))

Comment: This is a duplicate on [SE:Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600396/find-the-lambda-terme-without-free-variables-of-the-following-types)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## a) `p -> (q -> q)`

We need something to take a `p`,

```
\p -> …
```

and produce a `q -> q`, so we repeat, taking a q, and the only thing we can do is then return that q

```
\p -> \q -> q
```

we can add parens for emphasis:

```
\p -> (\q -> q)
```

## b) (p -> q) -> ((q -> r) -> (p -> r))

We repeat. Our term starts by taking a function from `p` to `q`:

```
\p2q -> …
```

It must return a function of type `((q -> r) -> (p -> r))`, so we start by returning something taking a function from `q` to `r`

```
\p2q -> \q2r -> …
```

And we now need it to produce an `r` given a `p`. There are only so many ways to piece together the available pieces:

```
\p2q -> \q2r -> \p -> q2r (p2q p)
```

Again, with parenthesis for emphasis:

```
\p2q -> (\q2r -> (\p -> q2r (p2q p)))
```

## c) `(p -> (q -> (q -> r))) -> (p -> (q -> r))`

Hmm, my naming convention falls a little short on this one ;)

First, our term takes a `(p -> (q -> (q -> r)))`:

```
\p2q2q2r -> …
```

Next, we must produce a term of type `(p -> (q -> r))`, so we let it take a `p`, and next take a `q`:

```
\p2q2q2r -> \p -> \q -> …
```

Producing an `r` now just involves piecing together what we have

```
\p2q2q2r -> \p -> \q -> ((p2q2q2r p) q) q
```

Hoped that helped with your homework ;)